# How to Run Bash Script for Scala

Tags: git, bash, scala

I'm breaking myself into Scala. I got "Hello, World" to echo on the terminal. WOOT!

Here's my new problem: Run `rails new <app>` by running it with scala. Improvement: It will `cd` into the `<app>` folder it will make and then run `git init` for you.

This is my problem and I want to make the bash script with Scala.

Here was my Hello World script (complete copy from scala lang):

```
#!/bin/sh
exec scala "$0" "$@"
!#
object HelloWorld extends App {
  println("Hello, World")
}
HelloWorld.main(args)
```

Does anyone know how to do this? Or how I could at least run `ls` with the terminal?

Also, is there a way to handle errors with a bash script?

Comment: Check out scala.sys.process: http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.10.4/index.html#scala.sys.process.package

Comment: As a new user, you'll want to use the REPL, just run "scala" and type at the prompt to try stuff out.  It might take a while with Process and friends.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can look at how a plugin like [**`sbt/sbt-git`**](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-git) does implement calls to git.

See the [`sbt/git/ConsoleGitRunner.scala`](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-git/blob/master/src/main/scala/com/typesafe/sbt/git/ConsoleGitRunner.scala):

```scala
private lazy val cmd = if(isWindowsShell) Seq("cmd", "/c", "git") else Seq("git")
```

It uses [`sbt.Process`](https://github.com/sbt/sbt/blob/0.13/util/process/src/main/scala/sbt/Process.scala).